# how to read exported environment variables in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, export, environment-variables

I have some environment variables exported in the terminal like`export my_server_port=1234`

I want to read the environment variable `my_server_port` from my TypeScript code.

I tried reading it using the following code,  but that doesn't seem to return anything:

```
let my_req = process.env.my_server_port;
```

I would like to know how can I retrieve the exported value for `my_server_port` in TypeScript?

Comment: So, you using node, right?

Comment: For me accessing exported variables via `process.env` works just fine.

Comment: yes I use node.

Comment: It would be good if you could provide more details about what exactly you are doing in which sequence in which environment, as i cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: ok this is the sequence of steps I am doing:
1)export my_service_port=1234 on my MAC localhost terminal 
2)Trying to read this variable in TypeScript using process.env and see the output:
    In ts:
    {let x = process.env.my_service_port;
    console.log('value of x is:', x);
     }
3)npm start: from terminal to execute above statements as part of my app
No value is displayed for of x after the execution
Please let me know if this info is sufficient?

Comment: I created a minimal version that runs a script via `npm start` and it also works. Are you exporting and executing the script in the same terminal instance?

Comment: yes both are from same terminal instance

Comment: Hard to tell what might be wrong then...

Comment: ```console.log(process.env)```. Is it there?

Comment: yes that works as expected with console.log(process.env)
Thank you Wainage!!